# How to extend object in a commonJS like fashion?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make sure all my code has this extend method:

```
Object.prototype.extend = function(obj) {
       for(i in obj)
          this[i] = obj[i];
};
```

If I want to provide that to my libraries can I just require it in my entry point? That doesn't seem right because I'm not exporting anything. Whats the best way to edit Object and apply those changes by requiring them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying `Object.prototype` is generally discouraged - especially when using modules. It will introduce changes that other modules are not aware of and might break them. Instead you should consider writing a `extendObject` module, that exports that function. Simply require that module and use the exported function:

```
var extendObject = require('extendObject');

extendObject(obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: But if I DO modify Objecy.prototype in a module, and other modules require that, will they get the new prototype as well?

Comment: The problem is they don't event need to require your module. If any module at any time requires the module that affects Object.prototype, all modules will get the amended Object.prototype - even those that may not be aware of the change (e.g. third party modules).